# Python Libvirt API for domtime actions

Tags: python, operating-system, libvirt, virsh

Does anybody know if python-libvirt has any API to perform 'domtime operations'.

I'm writing a python script that runs the command manually using `os` module.

```
...
os.system("virsh domtime %s --sync" % my_domain)
...
```

I want to use the libvirt API for that.

Do you know if it is possible?

I'm not finding any reference into the Documentation.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [the documentation](https://libvirt.org/python.html):

> The Python binding should be complete and are mostly automatically
>   generated from the formal description of the API in xml.

According to [the source of `domtime`](https://github.com/libvirt/libvirt/blob/4b9af8625a642339526b47eff718fab12c4b7cea/tools/virsh-domain-monitor.c#L1303), the command uses the calls `virDomainSetTime` and `virDomainGetTime`, which can be accessed through Python as `libvirt.virDomain.setTime` and `libvirt.virDomain.getTime`.

Comment: Hi Paulo. Thanks for you answer. What is the options to use the same parameters as "--now"? setTime(None, 1) ?

Comment: I'm not sure, to be honest. Why not just do `datetime.now()` and convert that to seconds? If you're on Python 3.3+ you can just do `date.timestamp()`.